Are Spire Healthcare doctors contracted to work 168 hours per week?
BBC News states that doctors are contracted by Spire Healthcare to work up to 168 hours per week.

The BBC also obtained testimony from doctors - contracted by the company to work up to 168 hours a week - who say long hours could put patients at risk
[...]
Resident medical officers, now called resident doctors, provide 24-hour cover at private hospitals. In some private hospitals, including Spire, these doctors are contracted to work up to 168 hours a week.
This may mean they work from 09:00 to 17:00 and then are on call until the following morning, when they work a day shift again and then repeat the pattern across a week.

There are only 168 hours in a week (24 x 7).
Is the claim that doctors may not be allowed any time off true?

This looks like pre brexit information (which is why I am not posting as an answer) but it should give an idea on the restrictions which appear to be a max of 48 hours a week. https://roadtouk.com/working-in-different-specialties/working-hours-of-a-doctor-in-the-nhs-uk/

@JoeW this was on today's TV news too. The linked BBC report says "Since 2009, the NHS has said its doctors should not work on average more than 48 hours a week." That would not cover much more than the day shift. These are not NHS doctors, but in private healthcare (which may be contracted to NHS).

There is a key distinction between being contracted to be available on call 168hr per week and being contracted to work 168hrs per week. The wording of the claim doesn't make this distinction clear enough.

@matt_black: The wording does make it pretty clear: "This may mean they work from 09:00 to 17:00 and then are on call until the following morning, when they work a day shift again and then repeat the pattern across a week."

@Brian My problem is that the title and final sentence of the question both brush over that distinction.

Even the 48 hours max in the NHS is heavily nuanced.
They average the hours out over a period - and that period includes 2 weeks of holiday, so they spread those 80 hours out over the other 10 weeks.  This means that you can be rota'd on for 56 hours a week.

@WeatherVane actually, just spoken to my wife about this, and that “shouldnt work more than 48 hours a week” claim is utter rubbish - my wife and her colleagues was regularly rota’d on for 60 and even 80 hour weeks during her hospital training, and that was from 2009 to 2014.  Doctors were also exempt from the working time directive.
